# Borrar pantalla desde terminal con PHP

Tags: php, linux, terminal

Resumiendo mucho, tengo este script al que llamo cls:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
    exec ('clear');
```

Asigno permisos de ejecución así:

```
$ chmod +x cls
```

Lo ejecuto de esta forma desde el terminal:

```
$ cls
```

¿Por qué no me borra la pantalla del terminal? Todos los demás comandos de Linux sí que me los ejecuta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma de borrar la pantalla desde un PHP cli es

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
    system ('clear');
```